# Nodejs Typescript Jest Unit Test Coverage shows some code to covered

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, test-coverage

This is my nodejs typescript class and written jest unit test for isHealthy() public method.

Test coverage shows that this.pingCheck() then block, catch and last return statement are not covered.
Please advise.

Can we do unit test for pingCheck private method ?

This my class

```
import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DependencyUtlilizationService } from '../dependency-utlilization/dependency-utlilization.service';
import { ComponentType } from '../enums/component-type.enum';
import { HealthStatus } from '../enums/health-status.enum';
import { ComponentHealthCheckResult } from '../interfaces/component-health-check-result.interface';
import { ApiHealthCheckOptions } from './interfaces/api-health-check-options.interface';
@Injectable()
export class ApiHealthIndicator {
  private healthIndicatorResponse: {
    [key: string]: ComponentHealthCheckResult;
  };
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly dependencyUtilizationService: DependencyUtlilizationService,
  ) {
    this.healthIndicatorResponse = {};
  }

  private async pingCheck(api: ApiHealthCheckOptions): Promise<boolean> {
    let result = this.dependencyUtilizationService.isRecentlyUsed(api.key);
    if (result) {
      await this.httpService.request({ url: api.url }).subscribe(() => {
        return true;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  async isHealthy(
    listOfAPIs: ApiHealthCheckOptions[],
  ): Promise<{ [key: string]: ComponentHealthCheckResult }> {
    for (const api of listOfAPIs) {
      const apiHealthStatus = {
        status: HealthStatus.fail,
        type: ComponentType.url,
        componentId: api.key,
        description: `Health Status of ${api.url} is: fail`,
        time: Date.now(),
        output: '',
        links: {},
      };
      await this.pingCheck(api)
        .then(response => {
          apiHealthStatus.status = HealthStatus.pass;
          apiHealthStatus.description = `Health Status of ${api.url} is: pass`;
          this.healthIndicatorResponse[api.key] = apiHealthStatus;
        })
        .catch(rejected => {
          this.healthIndicatorResponse[api.key] = apiHealthStatus;
        });
    }
    return this.healthIndicatorResponse;
  }
}
```

This is my unit test code. 
I get the following error when I run npm run test

(node:7876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

(node:7876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { DependencyUtlilizationService } from '../dependency-utlilization/dependency-utlilization.service';
import { ApiHealthIndicator } from './api-health-indicator';
import { ApiHealthCheckOptions } from './interfaces/api-health-check-options.interface';
import { HealthStatus } from '../enums/health-status.enum';

describe('ApiHealthIndicator', () => {
  let apiHealthIndicator: ApiHealthIndicator;
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let dependencyUtlilizationService: DependencyUtlilizationService;
  let dnsList: [{ key: 'domain_api'; url: 'http://localhost:3001' }];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ApiHealthIndicator,
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: new HttpService(),
        },
        {
          provide: DependencyUtlilizationService,
          useValue: new DependencyUtlilizationService(),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    apiHealthIndicator = module.get<ApiHealthIndicator>(ApiHealthIndicator);

    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
    dependencyUtlilizationService = module.get<DependencyUtlilizationService>(
      DependencyUtlilizationService,
    );
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(apiHealthIndicator).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('isHealthy should return status as true when pingCheck return true', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(dependencyUtlilizationService, 'isRecentlyUsed')
      .mockReturnValue(true);

    const result = apiHealthIndicator.isHealthy(dnsList);

    result.then(response =>
      expect(response['domain_api'].status).toBe(HealthStatus.pass),
    );
  });
  it('isHealthy should return status as false when pingCheck return false', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(dependencyUtlilizationService, 'isRecentlyUsed')
      .mockReturnValue(false);

    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'request').mockImplementation(config => {
      throw new Error('could not call api');
    });

    const result = apiHealthIndicator.isHealthy(dnsList);

    result
      .then(response => {
        expect(response['domain_api'].status).toBe(HealthStatus.fail);
      })
      .catch(reject => {
        expect(reject['domain_api'].status).toBe(HealthStatus.fail);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should define the status before initialize the unit test, try to grab some more logs using `console.log` and for the second test, added catch block to make sure you're grabing the failures